# java.io.IOException: FTP error: 553 Could not create file

Tags: java, ftp-server

I'm trying to save image in FTP server. But it giving error like java.io.IOException: FTP error: 553 Could not create file.

I call the method
upload("xxx.xx.2.36","ftpuser","xxxxxpos",imageFile,"ftp://ftpuser@xxx.xx.2.36/Item/");

```
public static void check(FTPClient ftp, String cmd, boolean succeeded) throws IOException {
    if (!succeeded) {
      throw new IOException("FTP error: " + ftp.getReplyString());
    }
  }

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
private static String today() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
  }

public static void upload(String server, String username, String Password,
        File imageFile, String destDir) {

     FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

        try {
             ftp.connect(server);
            check(ftp, "login", ftp.login(username, Password));

            System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            try {
              String destination = destDir;
              if (destination.endsWith("/")) {
                destination += today()+"-"+imageFile.getName();
                System.out.println("direc" +destination);
              }
              check(ftp, "store", ftp.storeFile(destination, input));
              System.out.println("Stored " + imageFile + " to " + destination + ".");
            } finally {
              input.close();
            }

            check(ftp, "logout", ftp.logout());

          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        finally {
            try {
                ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
```

After ftp.storeFile(destination, input) it giving error

Please help to solve this.

Comment: Does the path (directories) of the destination file exist ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972768/error-in-ftp-upload-553-could-not-create-file

Comment: check if you have permission to write in the target directory

Comment: yes. "ftp://172.xx.2.36/Item/" This my path for upload image.

Comment: yes i have permission.

Comment: I think problem with destination path. i don't know how to give the path.

Comment: with that link only i done the same thing but i'm not able to get where is wrong.

Comment: I given remote path as `"ftp://172.16.2.36/Item/"`